# Import P-CAD library files to Altium

Tags: altium, library, import

I have an old P-CAD library file and need to import it to Altium. The library file format is .LIB

I tried to use Import wizard -- P-CAD Libraries and select the file. But I receive a messeage; *the file is not recognized. Please select P-CAD PCB or schematic files.*

I have also tried to Add Library and open the file, but could not see any component on it.

How to import or open this type of files in Altium ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Altium claims [in this tutorial](https://techdocs.altium.com/display/ADOH/Moving+to+Altium+Designer+From+P-CAD) (and also [here](https://techdocs.altium.com/display/ADOH/Importing+and+Exporting+Design+Files)) that it can import P-CAD's `.lib` libraries.

I did a quick test, which was successful.  I have downloaded a P-CAD library Microchip.lib from [here](http://electronix.ru/forum/index.php?showtopic=6484).

1. in Altium.  File  → Import Wizard
   Click Next
2. title: **Select type of files to import**
   choose `P-CAD Designs and Libraries files`
   Click Next
3. title: **Importing P-CAD designs**
   Don't add any files (leave the list empty).  You only want to import libraries, but not designs.  I think, this is where the O.P. got stuck.
   Click Next
4. title: **Importing P-CAD *library* files**
   Add library(ies) which you wish to import.
   Click Next
5. I clicked Next in all of the remaining wizard pages, accepted defaults.
6. After I clicked Finish, Altium created a folder called `Imported Microchip.lib` inside are `.SchLib` and `.PcbLib` files.

On a different occasion, I have also successfully imported P-CAD libraries in `.p`, `.c`, `.d` format into Altium (downloaded [from here](https://bluegiga.zendesk.com/entries/22892136-BLE112-schematic-decal-and-PCB-layout-footprint-libraries)).

*p.s.*
This also worked for importing OrCAD libraries into Altium.  (Different choice for step 2., of course.)

Comment: In step no.4 : I receive the following message/error: Library file not recognized. Please select P-CAD library files. 
As I mentioned before, the format of the file is Altium Library (.LIB)

Comment: Do you suspect that the P-CAD library is too old, and Altium doesn't recognize its format?  Maybe you can ask someone who has got P-CAD software to open your old library (hopefully, P-CAD maintained backward compatibility with it's own old libraries) and save it in a some newer format which Altium can open.  [I've never run P-CAD myself, so these are only $0.02 guesses.]

Comment: As you mentioned it seems that Altium doesn't recognize this old format anymore !!